# QTP/UFT Testing: await-able WPF application(.net)

Tags: c#, wpf, qtp

I am newbie to UFT. I am using QTP 14.52. How we can test await-able WPF application? 
Need to add any extension?

In UFT object spy:

1. sync call--> shows the gridview as UIATable(in the object hierarchy) using UI Automation.
2. async call (to load data)--> show the application as  UIAObject(in the object hierarchy) and it is not expanded.

How can i get the UIATable in object spy with UIAutomation for async call?

Your support on this issue is highly appreciable.

Thanks,
RSG

Comment: What do you mean `await-able`? Tasks and asynchronous execution aren't specific to a stack. They are available to all applications. In fact, asynchronous event handlers in desktop applications were one of the earliest uses of `async/await`

Comment: I mean async and await only.

Comment: that doesn't mean anything though. That's how the *compiler* handles asynchronous operations. It doesn't change the application itself in any way. What it does mean is that if you click a button, the UI won't freeze until the handler completes whatever heavy job it's doing. That's no different than having code that used eg `BeginX/EndX`, or callbacks, or threads, or any other of the older asynchronous execution methods.